# Ansible check if inventory_hostname is in list

Tags: ansible

I am trying to check if `inventory_hostname` is in a list into an imported variable.

```
vars/users.yml file:
---
users:

  - username: user1
    comment: "User 1"
    group: admin
    password: "sha password"
    keys:
      active:
        - "ssh-rsa etc"
    admin: yes

  - username: user2
    comment: "User 2"
    group: users
    groups: deployer
    keys:
      active:
        - "ssh-rsa etc"
    hosts:
      user:
        - host1
        - host2
      deployer:
        - host3
```

I want to execute a task only if **inventory_hostname** is into any of hosts lists (user, deployer, others ...).

I tried this:

```
- name: Create users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    comment: "{{ item.comment | default('User {{item.username}}') }}"
    password: "{{ item.password | default('!') }}"
    state: "{{ item.state | default('present') }}"
    shell: "{{ item.shell | default('/bin/bash') }}"
    group: "{{ item.group | default('users') }}"
  with_items: '{{ users }}'
  when: item.username is defined and ((item.admin is defined and item.admin == True) or (item.hosts is defined and item.hosts.user is defined and inventory_hostname in item.hosts.user)
```

It works for **user1** (which have admin enabled) but not for **user2** (if this play is executed on **host1** which is included into user2's hosts.user list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well .. I tried your code snippet and it works well for both users. Only thing which can make it fail is that hostnames in `item.host.user` are not matching the `inventory_hostname`. You can try to debug the `inventory_hostname` before this task to see what are the inventory hostnames read by ansible and whether you have specified them correctly in `item.host.user` list.

```
- debug: var=inventory_hostname
```

Comment: Thanks Kanwar! I am happy that my snippet was working, in effect I was missing the domain name into item.host.user! :-(
One more question: how do you think it would be possible to check if inventory_hostname is into one of the subkeys of item.host (item.host.user or item.host.deployer) without checking one by one? Thanks!